# Why am I able to send UDP packet larger than my WIFI interface's MTU?

Tags: networking, wireshark, udp

I have written a simple python program to send a UDP datagram.

```py
import socket

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = '1.2.3.4'
print(host_ip)
port = 8080
message = b'0' * 65500

client_socket.sendto(message,(host_ip,port))
```

When I run this code, it successfully sends a UDP packet. Here's the wireshark log,

[image]

The MTU of my wireless interface is 1500 which I found out by running `ip link` command.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 58:11:22:82:c2:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:26:79:33:7c:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
```

I read that one cannot send a packet larger than an interface's MTU then how come the UDP packet was transmitted. Can somebody explain to me what is happening here?

PS: I tried sending this to a server that I own and I was able to receive the message as well.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv4 and IPv6 both support fragmentation below transport layer, though it doesn't always work as well as it should (some networks do not return the correct Path MTU indication, some networks drop fragments outright), but in this case the OS knows its local MTU and will fragment the packet accordingly.

In your case, the packet is fragmented at IP layer but the OS uses hardware offload so that fragmentation is actually handled by your NIC and is not visible to packet capture. (This can offer better performance as the OS doesn't need to queue multiple packets and copy chunks of your payload data around in memory.)

Use `ethtool -k wlan0 | grep -v '\[fixed\]'` to see the offload features that you can turn on/off. Most likely this is 'generic-segmentation-offload' or 'gso'; you can temporarily disable it using `ethtool -K wlan0 gso off`.

Additionally, there is a socket option that you can set through setsockopt() to opt out of fragmentation; the send() call will then return an error code for packets that are too big. For IPv4 the option is 'IP_MTU_DISCOVER', for IPv6 it's 'IPV6_MTU_DISCOVER'. See `man 7 ip`.

(If your Python version does not have these constants, find the actual values in /usr/include – they should be `10` for IP_MTU_DISCOVER and `23` for IPV6_MTU_DISCOVER. For example, `setsockopt(SOL_IP, 10, False)`.)

---

(As a side note, Wi-Fi interfaces have a potential maximum MTU of approx. 2304 – they just default to 1500 to remain compatible with the standard Ethernet configuration of 1500.)

Comment: Turning off gso and IP_MTU_DISCOVER didn't do anything. Also if the packet is automatically fragmented below transport layer then I should be able to send a very large packet as well. But when I specify the payload size greater than 65507, I get "message too long error"

Comment: "is automatically fragmented" does not imply infinity. Even with fragmentation, IPv4 is limited to packets of 65535 bytes including the header.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I tried logging packets using tcpdump i did notice that there were packet fragments. After that I also noticed that in wireshark when I click on the large udp packet, the bottom left shows reassembled ipv4 packet. I also came across a similar answer https://serverfault.com/a/645892